# Work with projects created in old QGIS version after update

Tags: qgis

If I install the new version of QGIS, can I work on the projects that I created in the old version ?

Comment: Yes, you can open porjects created with e.g. 2.18 with 3.10 - if that was the question.

Comment: As an alternative, you can have several versions of QGIS installed on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

When you save them again for the first time they will be updated to the new version.

Backward compatibility is not as good.

Comment: note that the oldest the previous version are the more likely that some part of old project may be broke (thing like labelling or anything using expression may not work anymore due to change in labelling engine or expression syntax) but it's usually not an hard thing to fix